# Is it possible to add an eventlistener on an object that is modified through javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a table where the sum of the rows are updated with javascript when a user changes the quantity within a popup modal. I want to be able to update the grand total of all my rows every time the total of a row change.

I have tried to add an event listener onchange and oninput on the total of each of my row  but it doesn't work. I have tried to find a workaround by adding an event listener on the quantity the user is changing but to no effect. I have tried the code in the console and it is working but the event-listener doesn't seem to trigger.

```
 document.getElementById("work_quantity_<%= @work_detail.id %>").addEventListener("change", grandTotal)


 var work_detail_quantity = document.getElementById("work_quantity_<%= @work_detail.id %>").value;
 var work_detail_block = document.getElementById("work-<%= @work_detail.id %>");
 var quant = work_detail_block.getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
  quant.innerHTML = work_detail_quantity+" <%= @work_detail.work_resource.unit_measure%>";


function grandTotal() {
  var sub_total = document.getElementById("subtotal_lign").innerHTML
  var table = document.getElementById("invoice_summary"), sumVal = 0;

  for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
  {
      sumVal = sumVal+ parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[4].innerText.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, ''));
  }
  document.getElementById("subtotal_lign").innerHTML = sumVal.toFixed(2) + ' €' ;
};
```

If someone could give me a hint it would be more than appreciated, I am a rookie in javascript. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Have a try with MutationObservers, listen for content changes.

Comment: call the function that updates the total at the end of the event listener of each row.

Comment: How is the user changing the quantity in a row? The `change` event is for user inputs, so add the event listener there.

Comment: @Barmar The user can change the quantity in a modal that pops up when it wants to edit the quantity. The code I published earlier in the description is exactly what you advice me to do but it doesn't work :/ . The event listener is on the field that is modified by user within the modal. The event listener is not trigger.

Comment: I am gonna check  MutationObservers which is new to me @Maciej Kwas. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The code that copies from the modal to the table should perform the calculations then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to parse the DOM like that to get the values.

### Solution 1

You get the object that contains the values of your table form Ruby. Something like that:

`var works = <%= @works.to_json %>;`

Then, when a user updates his order, you first update the object and then you update the table based on the updated object.

### Solution 2

When a user update his order, you send the update to your server and you update the table in the server side.

### Solution 3 (Not recommended)

If you still want to do it by parsing the DOM, have a look at [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen the changes in your table.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

I thought that what I wrote below was working but actually the grand total is always one computation behind as it is doing the sum of the rows before the total of the modified row has been updated after a change of quantity.

---

Ok it is working with a workaround, but I still believe MutationObservers could be a good way to resolve this kind of problem in the future

[Good tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQ1N_EP07xs&ab_channel=SteveGriffith): for MutationObservers

To make my event listener work I add to define it before the change in the quantity is made by the user (stupid isn't it)

1) **Add the event listener to the object you are tracking**

```
document.getElementById("work_quantity_<%= @work_detail.id %>").addEventListener("input", grandTotal)
```

2) **This is where my object is changed with javascript**

```
var work_detail_block = document.getElementById("work-<%= @work_detail.id %>");
  var quant = work_detail_block.getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
  quant.innerHTML = work_detail_quantity+" <%= @work_detail.work_resource.unit_measure%>";
```

3) **I define the function which is called in the step 1**

```
function grandTotal() {
  var sub_total = document.getElementById("subtotal_lign").innerHTML
  var table = document.getElementById("invoice_summary"), sumVal = 0;

  for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
  {
    sumVal = sumVal+ parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[4].innerText.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, ''));
  }
document.getElementById("subtotal_lign").innerHTML = sumVal.toFixed(2) + ' €' ;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I confess, I haven't tried this per say; but I did try in jQuery a similar thing, mainly because your example lacks the detail of the table;

but you need to trigger the event when a change occurs, I assume here your not using standard input fields, so are you using like <td contenteditable></td>, they can't be monitored for change, but keyup and blur can be monitored, so if you want to trigger the calc on blur, when that event occurs, trigger your table sum event...

I'd actually use jQuery for this but here goes ...

```
document.getElementById("work_quantity_<%= @work_detail.id %>").addEventListener("change", grandTotal)
 ...
function grandTotal() {
    var sub_total = document.getElementById("subtotal_lign").innerHTML
    var table = document.getElementById("invoice_summary"), sumVal = 0;

    for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        sumVal = sumVal+ parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[4].innerText.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, ''));
    }
    document.getElementById("subtotal_lign").innerHTML = sumVal.toFixed(2) + ' €' ;
};

// something like this
(function() {
    // i assume it's cell[4] that is being edited, and it's like contenteditable
    var table = document.getElementById("invoice_summary");

    for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        /* assign listener on the cell, 
        when it blurs, trigger the update, 
        you could also monitor keyup
        */
        table.rows[i].cells[4].addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
            document.getElementById("work_quantity_<%= @work_detail.id %>").dispatchEvent("change", grandTotal);

        });

    }

})();
```

Comment: David thank you for your help and sorry for the lack of infos regarding the table. Unfortunately the cell[4] was not clickable neither editable. The cell is changed/modified through the input made on a modal as explained in a comment below the question.